Google Apps Script onEventUpdated Trigger Fires Multiple Times for All-Day Events
I am working on a GSuite Add-on and have created a trigger to handle calendar event updates. Here's the setup:
const trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger(handleCalendarChangeTrigger)
      .forUserCalendar(calendarId)
      .onEventUpdated()
      .create();

function handleCalendarChangeTrigger(ev) {
  const calendarId = ev.calendarId;
  const recentEvents = CalendarService.getRecentUpdatedEvents(calendarId, 5);
  recentEvents.forEach((event) => {
    const calendarEvent = CalendarApp.getEventById(event.id);
    const location = calendarEvent.getLocation();
    if (location) {
      return;
    } else {
      calendarEvent.setLocation('MARK LOCATION');
      return;
    }
  });
}


When the calendar event is an All-Day event, the onEventUpdated trigger fires multiple times. For example, creating or updating an All-Day event can result in two or more trigger executions.
If my trigger function modifies multiple fields (e.g., both setLocation and setDescription), the number of executions increases further.
This behavior doesn’t occur (or occurs less frequently) with non-All-Day events.
I want to know are there specific properties of All-Day events that cause them to trigger updates more frequently?
And is there a way to avoid or mitigate the multiple trigger executions?
For example, can I prevent updates made within the trigger function (e.g., setLocation or setDescription) from retriggering the onEventUpdated trigger?

Welcome to StackOverflow! May I ask if you are encountering any error other than the multiple trigger executions?
